# Access to the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\19.xml' is denied

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a grid view on page. When i click on a select button of grid view. I am getting an exception like this

> Error Message:  Access to the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\19.xml' is denied. 
>   here 19 is the id of the record in the grid view.

Actually it was working fine till yesterday. but suddenly raised the exception.

Every thing here is done by a web service.Web service works fine on all pages but only on one page.The exception is raises only on production system not on development system

It is occurring on only one page. How to resolve this.

Comment: Are you reading or creating XML file?

Comment: creating xml of a page and filling all the controls from xml file

Comment: "It is occurring on only one page." You are able to edit/update xml using other pages?

Comment: no.. there is no such file like 19.xml in inetsrv folder

Comment: So you dont have other pages which updates/creates XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your create/write/reading rights on the folder the xml is in.

Your application pool identity probably does not have the appropriate rights to create/modify/open the file, causing this error to occur.

Please check the security settings and see if that fixes the error.

Comment: How did you check? The IIS user should have access to this file.

Comment: can u please tell me what are the properties i need to check

Comment: Right click folder > properties. Then select the security tab and see what rights the user (that you've set in IIS) currently has. If the user has no create/modify/read rights, add these and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Server.MapPath` if xml documents are located under the root of web-app.

```
string value="19.xml";
string file=Server.MapPath("~/folder/" + value);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to [move your XML data to a DataTable](http://sandeep-aparajit.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-convert-datatable-to-xml-in-c.html).. hence remove neediness to access directly your file. When everything is done simply save back your changes into the respective xml file.